# Proving that product of two matrix is Singular

Tags: matrices

> Let $A$ be a $3\times 2$ matrix and $B$ be a $2\times 3$ matrix. Show that $C = A\cdot B$ is a singluar matrix.

Not sure how to proceed with this. How can it be always be singular if we are randomly multiplying two matrix

Comment: Hint: think about the rank.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beauty of linear algebra is that it gives us the language to explain the same situation in many different terms.

For example, an $p$ by $p$ matrix $D$ being singular is equivalent to

- $det(D)=0$
- $rank(D)<p$
- Their existing some vector other than the zero vector in $null(D)$

Using the second equivalence $rank(D)<p$ this tells us that to show a matrix $C=AB$ is singular, we must show that $rank(C)<3$ (since the product of $A\in R^{3x2}$ and $B\in R^{2x3}$ is in $R^{3x3}$).

Rectangular, non square matrices have a maximum rank of their smallest dimension (I mean spatial dimension rather than vector space dimension).

i.e. $$A\in R^{a x b},\quad rank(A)\le a \quad (a\le b)$$

We can use the fact that $rank(AB)\le min(rank(A), rank(B))$.

We have

$$rank(A)\le 2 \\ rank(B)\le 2$$

So

$$rank(C)=rank(AB)\le 2 < 3$$

So $C$ is singular.